# Why does Spring Data Rest mangle / corrupt data when binding to entity?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-cloud-feign

On the client and server side, I have:

```
@Data
public class Car {
  private Long id;
}

@Data
public class GroupMember {
    private Long id;
    private Group group; // has only single field, id
    private Car car;
    private Car groupCar;
}
```

Note: On the server side these are entities. (I'm using Spring Boot Data Rest to save.)

The client creates a car and then tries to create a group member for that car as follows:

```
Car car = new Car();
car = client.save(car); // this works fine

GroupMember gm = new GroupMember();
gm.setGroup(new Group(1L));
gm.setGroupCar(car);
gm.setCar(car);
client.save(gm); // this fails
```

`client` is a instance of `CarClient`:

```
@FeignClient(name = "car")
public interface CarClient {
    
    @PostMapping("/api/cars")
    public Car save(Car car);
    
    @PostMapping("/api/groupMembers")
    public GroupMember save(GroupMember groupMember);
    
}
```

`client.save(GroupMember)` fails with

```
[409] during [POST] to [http://car/api/groupMembers] [CarClient#save(GroupMember)]: [{"cause":{"cause":{"cause":null,"message":"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'groupCarId', table 'cars.dbo.GroupMember'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."}
```

After turning on trace on the server side, I can see that `groupCar` (and `car`) is null:

```
2022-06-30 16:25:47.333 TRACE 16840 --- [http-nio-9009-exec-1] .w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : Arguments: [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation@5ca2b05f, Resource { content: GroupMember(id=10640, group=Group(id=1), car=null, groupCar=null), links: [] }, org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler@47f7b8a2, */*]
```

Also, the `GroupMember` id was set to the car id, 10640!!

Why did Spring Data Rest incorrectly bind the properties of GroupMember?

**Update**

Because Spring Data Rest appears to be broken in its binding, I created a controller as follows:

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/groupMember")
@Slf4j
public class GroupMemberController {

    private final GroupMemberRepository repo;
    
    @PostMapping
    public GroupMember save(@RequestBody GroupMember groupMember) {
        log.info("GROUP MEMBER is {}", groupMember);
        return repo.save(groupMember);

    }
}
```

and then revised my FeignClient to point to that for saving a GroupMember:

```
@FeignClient(name = "car")
public interface CarClient {
    
    @PostMapping("/api/cars")
    public Car save(Car car);
    
    @PostMapping("/groupMember")
    public GroupMember save(GroupMember groupMember);
    
}
```

This works as expected. I can see from the log that:

```
2022-07-01 13:02:04.637  INFO 764 --- [nio-9009-exec-1] com.example.GroupMemberController    : GROUP MEMBER is GroupMember(id=null, group=Group(id=1), car=car(id=10653), groupCar=Security(id=10653))
```

Am I doing something wrong with Spring Data Rest or can it not handle POSTing this type of data?

Comment: From your Entity object description it appears that your method `gm.setGroupCar(car)` would insert the id of car into the `groupCarId` field of your dbo. But as you can see car and groupCar are null. This may be because you may have not read the return value of the `public Car save(Car car)` method and set it to the car object again i.e. `car = client.save(car)`.

Comment: @user3747396 - Yes, I forgot this assignment `car = client.save(car)` in the OP. But my original source code has this yet the issue is still there. I just forgot to copy it into the OP. I've updated the OP. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Data Rest tries to deserialize the `Car` fields in `GroupMember` using URIs. There are no URIs provided by the client though. Instead, `groupCar` and `car` are nested objects in the JSON.

Adding `@RestResource(exported = false)` on the two car fields within `GroupMember` (on the server side) resolves the issue by telling Spring Data Rest to expect nested objects instead of URIs.

Alternatively, an `EntityModel<GroupMember>` could be passed from the client.